# Windows forms not rendering buttons, images, launching application at runtime - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having this issue for a while now on some machines, when the user runs the application all the buttons, images, menu items, almost everything goes blank.

My first thought was: I have a separate thread using BackgroundWorker updating a StatusBar and I've read that this can cause issues to form rendering.

I found an [article](http://www.devsol.com.br/blog/?p=458) (it's in portuguese, since I'm a Brazilian) that explains this is a issue caused by a security plugin installed by our banks called Warsaw. One of the solutions was to contact the developers to have them analyze your software so the plugin will work correctly. I've done this and I'm waiting for their response.

The other solution is to sign our assembiles so the plugin may recognize as a trusted software, this is good but not free of charge unfortunately.

Now, here's an example of my application looks like when it's launched with this issue:

[A form with a GridView](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cco5s92f7khdc69/erro1.png?dl=0)

The code for the separate thread as mentioned above:

```
    int countAlerta = 0;
    int countAlertaRFRP = 0;
    int countAlertaAditivo = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        else
        {
            alertaToolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Continuando a verificação...";
            alertaToolStripStatusLabel.IsLink = false;
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        lock (new object())
        {
            countAlerta = new BLL.AlertasBLL().CountRVSRAS();
            countAlertaRFRP = new BLL.AlertasBLL().CountRFRP();
            countAlertaAditivo = new BLL.AlertasBLL().CountAditivos();
        }
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        alertaToolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Verificando...";
        alertaToolStripStatusLabel.IsLink = false;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (countAlerta + countAlertaAditivo + countAlertaRFRP > 0)
        {
            alertaToolStripStatusLabel.Text = "ALERTA: Verifique!!!";
            alertaToolStripStatusLabel.IsLink = true;
            alertaToolStripStatusLabel.Font = new Font(alertaToolStripStatusLabel.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
        else
        {
            alertaToolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Não existem alertas";
            alertaToolStripStatusLabel.IsLink = false;
        }
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Disappearing acts like that are usually caused by a GDI+ leak in a program.  Use Task Manager to diagnose, add the USER Objects and GDI Objects columns.  Use Dispose() correctly in a program to fix, GC.Collect() is a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant , I found this interesting [article](http://madgeek.com/articles/leaks/leaks.en.html) about memory leaks and I'm doing some research to clear my code.